# Django - How to conect Pentaho Kettle ETL with wep app

Tags: django, etl, kettle

I have a Django application where users can upload big dataset in PostgreSQL db. I would like to use an ETL tool like [Pentaho Kettle](http://kettle.pentaho.com/) to do the upload job. Later, I would like to use Kettle for data mining and transformations.

However, I have no idea how I to connect my Django app to Kettle. I am not sure what version of Kettle is needed, do I need spoon, or carte?

How can I trigger the job from django python and how to pass the request.FILES of my app to Kettle?

Can you explain the general steps or point to documentation or examples?

Comment: So do I understand this correctly? You have a web service in Django that users can send data to, and you want that data to flow into your PostgreSQL db. Either way the docs are here:http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Latest+Pentaho+Data+Integration+%28aka+Kettle%29+Documentation I would stick to the latest version for interacting with web services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) make your data transformation on kettle (spoon.sh).

2) do a shellscript launching kitchen or pan and this transformation.

3) trigger this shellscript from your django app after the data is uploaded to the server.